# R ggplot add text above plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data consists of the variables `log R ratio`, `sample_id` and `replicate`.
I have made a boxplot with ggplot.

```
replicate_to_R$replicate <-factor(replicate_to_R$replicate, levels=c( "3", "4", "8","12" ), labels=c("3", "4", "8","12"))

replicate_to_R$sample_id <-factor(replicate_to_R$sample_id, levels=c(74,76,78,79,80), labels=c(18,20,22,23,24))
# boxplot
ggplot(aes(y=logRratio, x=sample_id, fill=replicate), data=replicate_to_R) + 
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1)) + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("steelblue4","steelblue3","steelblue2","steelblue1")) + theme(panel.grid.major.x =element_blank()) + 
theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
theme(axis.text = element_text(size=14, color="black"))
```

I want to add information on call rate for each sample in the top of the plot. Is there a way to add this additional information to the plot?

Comment: [`geom_text`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html) might be quite usefull for this. Furthermore, a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) would be nice

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` graphics use the `grid` graphics system, so you can use `grid` functions to annotate them:

```
library("grid")
grid.text("my text", x = 0.5, y = 0.5)
```

will put your text dead center in the graphics window. See `?grid.text` after loading the package for details about the coordinate system, but basically, the default system is relative to the entire graphics window.